# typedef function pointer inheritance

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I can have a typedef function pointer in a class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{

public:

typedef T (*fptr)(T);

  void doSomething(fptr my_fptr) { /*...*/ }

};
```

and this works fine. but if I inherit from such a class, as below:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass
{

public:

typedef T (*fptr)(T);

  virtual void doSomething(fptr my_fptr) = 0;

};

template<typename T>
class MyOtherClass: public MyClass<T>
{

public:

  void doSomething(fptr my_fptr) { /*...*/ }

};
```

the compiler complains that fptr is undefined. is there a way of inheriting function pointer typedefs like this? thanks,
james

Comment: What compiler are you using? Mine doesn't complain about this.

Comment: @Seb Rose: I guess you are using VS... that is a known issue with that compiler. The code according to the standard should not compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to inherit public typedefs like that.

Did you try something like this to make sure the compiler know it's a parent type:

```
void doSomething(typename MyClass<T>::fptr my_fptr) { /*...*/ }
```

Comment: this did it... I just missed the typename at the beginning.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is not with inheritance, but with the fact that a template is inheriting from the instantiation of another template passing it's own template argument as parameter. That is, it is inheriting from a dependent-type (`MyClass<T>` is dependent on the type `T`).

The language requires that the template is verified before performing the type substitution, and during that first pass, all non-dependent names are verified. When the compiler sees `fptr` it is not dependent on the type `T`, so it tries to locate it outside of your template as a namespace level symbol and fails. It is not allowed to instantiate `MyBase` with the type (there is no type for the substitution) and as such the whole `MyBase` is an unknown and no symbols can be looked up there (without substituting the type, the compiler cannot know whether there is an specific specialization of `MyBase`).

The simplest solution is adding a local typedef:

```
typedef MyBase<T> base_type;
typedef typename base_type::fptr fptr;
```

or fully qualify the call:

```
void doSomething( typename MyClass<T>::fptr ) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler needs more information due to the templating:

try 
`typename MyClass<T>::fptr`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the definition is in a base class that depends on a template parameter (known as a *dependent base class*); it's not known until the template is instantiated what that base class actually is; different specialisations could have different members. So you have to explicitly state that it's a type, defined in the base class:

```
template<typename T>
class MyOtherClass: public MyClass<T>
{
    typedef typename MyClass<T>::fptr fptr;
    // now fptr is available in this class template
};
```

To access members of a dependent base class, you can refer to them as either `MyClass<T>::member` or `this->member`.